# Why does the Hertzsprung–Russell diagram's x-axis go from large temperatures to lower?

Tags: observational-astronomy, history, luminosity, classification, hr-diagram

In my textbook, the H–R diagram’s y-axis is $\log(L/L_{\odot})$ and values are higher as we go higher on the scale, but the x-axis is $\log(T_\text{eff})$ and gets smaller as we proceed to the right.

This confuses me. Why not let the x-axis go from lower values to higher values? This will also help visualising the “linear” relation between the luminosity and the temperature of a star in the main sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Originally, what was plotted was *luminosity against colour*, and by colour I mean the wavelength of the peak intensity. Short wavelengths on the left, and long on the right, as you would expect.

[image: stars-planets-galaxies-qa.com]

Now since stars emit (nearly) black body radiation, there is a close relationship between colour and temperature. I suspect that the reason that the x axis isn't inverted when temperature is used is just inertia:- We have always plotted out H-Z diagrams like this and we will keep doing so.

Comment: Originally what was plotted was absolute magnitude versus spectral type. If colour is on the x-axis then the diagram is known as a colour magnitude diagram.

Comment: As indeed the picture in your answer illustrates.

Answer (score 8):

The original Hertzsprung-Russell diagrams constructed by Henry Russell and Eijnar Hertzsprung consisted of absolute magnitude on the y-axis and a spectral type or an indicator of spectral type on the x-axis. Below you can see an original HR diagram produced by Russell in 1913.

[image: Original HR diagram]

When the diagrams were constructed, it was *not at all clear* what the sequence of spectral types or spectral type indicators actually meant. It turned out of course that the sequence (in modern day parlance O,B,A,F,G,K,M) actually corresponds to *decreasing* temperature.

Astronomers have simply stuck with this convention to the present day, there is no particular reason for that. Most HR diagrams are now plotted with temperature (decreasing) along the x-axis, although that is not what the original HR diagram was.

Comment: It's one of those charming reminders of the brilliant history of astronomy. Since it isn't final yet, new letters were added just a few years ago, one might as well wait with ordering and naming it logically until one day everything is known...

Comment: You can see the scan of Russell's 1914 diagram at NASA ADS [here](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1914PA.....22..275R/0000285.000.html).